# Why PageSpeed shows Unattributable JavaScript execution time?

Tags: javascript, performance, pagespeed-insights

I am seeing Unattributable JavaScript execution time. How can I determine what is causing the issue?
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mz5TI.png)

I have tested by removing third party scripts but that didn't help. Not sure what is causing the Unattributable JavaScript execution time.

Comment: If you repeat the test, do you get consistent times when it comes to unattributable JS? You could also use another performance testing website, like [GT Metrix](https://gtmetrix.com), and see if you can find the similar time there. Or, if you're inclined to do so, you could always start by removing bits of your Javascript, and see when there's a significant drop in measured unattributable time.

Answer (score 1):

Unattributable means that PSI can't determine what triggered the JavaScript that was running (the screenshot doesn't give any context, so I'm just assuming this was unattributable javascript and not layout, painting, etc *triggered* by javascript).

At that point it might make sense to turn to the other audits available in the report rather than focusing on this one. Alternatively, you could try to see if removing first-party code helps to narrow down the root cause of this time.

There's not much more advice that can be given without a URL to test or more information than just that single line from the PSI report.