# "Unattributable" in reduce javascript excution time in Page Speed Insights tool? What does it mean and how to fix?

Tags: next.js, pagespeed-insights

I've recently run my website through [PageSpeed Insights tool](https://pagespeed.web.dev/) and encountered an issue where it reported an "Unattributable" in reduce javascript excution time. I'm unsure what this signifies and how to address it. Could someone please provide insights into what this means and how to resolve it?

[for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1BJjg.png)

Here's what I've tried so far:

- Checked Google's documentation for PageSpeed Insights, but couldn't find any information about this specific error.
- Reviewed my website's source code and configurations for any potential issues related to attribution, but haven't found any obvious issues.

Any guidance or assistance on resolving this "Unattributable" would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Unfortunately "Unattributable" means PSI isn't able to attribute the main-thread time to any particular source, so it's not clear what to do about it. See this similar question from a few days ago for a few ideas: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77961882/why-pagespeed-shows-unattributable-javascript-execution-time